# Given the Process ID can I know whether it has accessed the cache memory of CPU recently?

Tags: linux, caching, operating-system, assemblies, virtual-memory

I know the process ID of process X. After my process was preempted when it was scheduled again can I determine that process X was scheduled in between that time?

Can I know if process X updated the Cache Memory or not given its process ID?

Are there assembly code or API to do this in linux? Can anyone suggest coding examples or any technique?

Comment: `Can I determine that process X was scheduled in between that time?` Do they have the same scheduling class? What class do they have?

Comment: `Can I know if process X updated the Cache Memory or not given its process ID?` You mean file cache or CPU cache?

Comment: I know that process X has a large globally declared array. When the array is accessed that array is cached in the CPU cache. Now I want to know from a different process Y that weather process X accessed the CPU cache or not as process X and process Y have different virtual address the cache has the mechanism to see which process data is in which cache line?

Answer (score 0):

It is not a "process" which access the [CPU cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache). It is any execution of machine instruction on the CPU core.

In particular, when a core is running in kernel mode, it is by definition not running in a process, and it is obviously using the CPU cache (since every memory access goes thru the cache)

So your question does not have any sense, if you speak of the CPU cache.

The file system cache (sometimes called [page cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache)) is managed by the kernel, and you can't really attribute it to some specific process (e.g two processes reading the same file would use the same cached data). It is related to the mere action of accessing a file data (by whatever process doing that). See e.g. [linuxatemyram](http://linuxatemyram.com/)

You might perhaps get some measure *system-wide* about CPU cache or file system cache, probably thru [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) (see also [oprofile](http://oprofile.sourceforge.net/))

Comment: I know that process X has a large globally declared array. When the array is accessed that array is cached in the CPU cache. Now I want to know from a different process Y that weather process X accessed the CPU cache or not as process X and process Y have different virtual address the cache has the mechanism to see which process data is in which cache line?

Answer (score 0):

Can I know if process X updated the Cache Memory or not given its process ID?

If you are talking about CPU cache, then no. Both data cache and instruction cache are transparent to the system. There is no way to find out if it was update by a program x. But yes it will be used to speed up execution for sure.